# Opening Multiple New Pages in Browsers from the console

Tags: javascript, browser, console.log

I'm trying to use the browser console to get some data. I've managed to make an array of anchor elements. The DOM has a `.click()` method. When I run the following it only launches one new browser tab

```
links.forEach(function(element) {
  element.click();
});
```

the tab launched corresponds to the last link in the `links` array, so it feels like it may be a closure issue. The variables are the correct format as I'm able to execute `links[0].click() links[1].click() links[2].click() ...` and download the files from my browser by incrementing the index by hand. But I have 68 of these links and would like to automate it. Any help?

update:

```
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].click();
  console.log(i);
}
```

only opens the last link as well. And prints out 68 numbers.

update2:
Here's some context on what motivated this question http://harrymoreno.com/2014/12/30/Scraping-links-with-your-browser.html

Comment: You want to programmatically open 68 tabs on the end-user's machine?

Comment: Heyaaah, that's a job for the fabulous for-man and his friend, the incredible incrementor ... : `for ( var i = 0; i < 68; i++ ) ...`

Comment: @JonathanSampson on my machine, yes.

Comment: @AxelAmthor that doesn't work. And shouldn't as it's equivalent to the `forEach`

Comment: @HarryMoreno Sorry, if this is something you're wanting to personally do what is the purpose of tagging [cross-browser]?

Comment: @JonathanSampson I'd like a solution that is cross-browser compatible. I think this is a browser related issue - perhaps I can open one tab due to security measures, or whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add this before the click():

```
element.target = "_blank";
```

It will open every links in a new tab/window.